# I can't install WordPress on an existing database

Tags: php, wordpress

Today I was trying to install a new copy of WordPress on my local machine. There was a working copy of a site in there that I accidentally deleted. So I tried to reinstall WordPress on that existing database. Everything was fine, but in the last stage of the installation a weird message was coming up. It was saying `Please provide a valid username.` and there wasn't a field to provide a username, instead the text `User(s) already exists.` I have never come around this and neither have I heard of it. I am curious to know why WordPress is wanting a username when the field is locked. Is this a bug or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced it a few days ago, fixed it this way.

**1.** At first exported (backup) old database.

**2.** Installed a new copy of `WordPress` with a new empty database (settings should be using your old database username, password, etc).

**3.** Imported the old database to new installation.

**4.** Uploaded the `uploads` folder (images) to new installation.

Problem solved, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thats how solved it. But I wanted to know why this happened in this latest 3.7 version of wordpress. why they wants an username but there is no place to give. Thanks again. I appreciate your afford.

Comment: Welcome! I don't know it, didn't dig in to it, it was just a project that needed to be copied to another one.

Comment: thats right, and mine too. maybe in other time i wouldn't have noticed it. but now i feel curious. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I am adding this answer as this page comes up at the top of search engine results for "Please provide a valid username"

If your WordPress installation is in a subfolder of an existing website...

e.g. www.example.com/dev/

The username will not be accepted if you have a `.htaccess` file at the root of the website.

1. Rename the `.htaccess` file to something else.
2. Continue with the WordPress installation.
3. Then rename the `.htaccess` file back to what it was.